# How to distinguish each class in intent?

Tags: android

This is what I make in `RadioGroup`.

```
main_rdg_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener { radioGroup, i ->
    when (i) {
        R.id.rdb_main_mainCheck -> {
            Log.d("MainClass", "mainGrp")
        }

        R.id.rdb_main_sub_01_Check -> {
            Log.d("MainClass", "sub_01_Grp")
            main_intent = Intent(this, SubActivity_01::class.java)
        }

        R.id.rdb_main_sub_02_Check -> {
            Log.d("MainClass", "sub_02_Grp")
            main_intent = Intent(this, SubActivity_02::class.java)
        }
    }
} // radio GRP
```

and I want to check class in button action. but it doesn't work.

How can I distinguish each class? (`MainActivity`, `SubActivity_01`, `SubActivity_02`)

```
main_send_buttton.setOnClickListener {
    Log.d("MainClass", "mainButton")

    when (main_intent) {

        MainActivity::class.java -> {
            Log.d("MainClass", "MainActivity")
        }

        SubActivity_01::class.java -> {
            Log.d("MainClass", "SubActivity_01")
        }

        SubActivity_02::class.java -> {
            Log.d("MainClass", "SubActivity_02")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, the variable in your `when()` is an `Intent` type variable, and all the cases you provide are class type. They are completely different thing, of course will never be matched.

You can use integer to distinguish different cases like 0, 1, 2.